# how to filter the repeated data of json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

as you can see and test in the code snippet I have this function which queries and brings the data of a getjson, what I need is not to repeat the same data.

how can I filter repeated results so they do not appear?

```js
  var cuit = "30712413871";
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/av/v1/vencimientos/" + cuit, function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      var fecha = result.data[i].vencimiento;
      var periodo = fecha.substr(0, 7);
      console.log(result.data[i].idImpuesto);
      buscarChoice(result.data[i].idImpuesto, result.data[i].anticipoCuota, result.data[i].vencimiento, result.data[i].tipoOperacion, periodo);
    }
  });



function buscarChoice(num, op, venc, tipo, per) {
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/parametros/v1/impuestos/", function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      if (result.data[i].idImpuesto == num) {
        var table = document.getElementById("AFIP_edit");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


        cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].idImpuesto;
        cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].descImpuesto;
        cell3.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AFIP</label>';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table id="AFIP_edit" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Impuesto</th>
      <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tb">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you want ?

```js
var cuit = "30712413871";
var already_here = [];
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/av/v1/vencimientos/" + cuit, function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
if(already_here.includes(result.data[i].idImpuesto)) {
continue;
}
      var fecha = result.data[i].vencimiento;
      var periodo = fecha.substr(0, 7);
      console.log(result.data[i].idImpuesto);
      buscarChoice(result.data[i].idImpuesto, result.data[i].anticipoCuota, result.data[i].vencimiento, result.data[i].tipoOperacion, periodo);
      already_here.push(result.data[i].idImpuesto);
    }
  });



function buscarChoice(num, op, venc, tipo, per) {
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/parametros/v1/impuestos/", function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      if (result.data[i].idImpuesto == num) {
        var table = document.getElementById("AFIP_edit");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


        cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].idImpuesto;
        cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].descImpuesto;
        cell3.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AFIP</label>';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table id="AFIP_edit" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Impuesto</th>
      <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tb">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

BTW, browser support for the `.includes()` method I used is not great, so I recommend using a `for` loop to iterate through the items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution using array.filter. If you will be supporting older versions of IE you will need a polyfil fill to use the method.

A separate note, is there a version of the `/soa.afip.gob.ar/parametros/v1/impuestos/` api call that can return you just the data for the one id you are looking up?  If not, you should call that api once and store the list. That way you will only make 2 ajax calls, rather than 1+ 1 per item in data set.

```js
  var cuit = "30712413871";
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/av/v1/vencimientos/" + cuit, function(result) {
    var ids = {};
    var noDups = result.data.filter(function(item) {
      if(ids[item.idImpuesto]){
         return false;
      }
      ids[item.idImpuesto] = true;
      return true;
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < noDups.length; i++) {
      var fecha = noDups[i].vencimiento;
      var periodo = fecha.substr(0, 7);
      console.log(noDups[i].idImpuesto);
      buscarChoice(noDups[i].idImpuesto, noDups[i].anticipoCuota, noDups[i].vencimiento, noDups[i].tipoOperacion, periodo);
    }
  });



function buscarChoice(num, op, venc, tipo, per) {
  $.getJSON("https://soa.afip.gob.ar/parametros/v1/impuestos/", function(result) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      if (result.data[i].idImpuesto == num) {
        var table = document.getElementById("AFIP_edit");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);


        cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].idImpuesto;
        cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].descImpuesto;
        cell3.innerHTML = '<label class="hidden">AFIP</label>';
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table id="AFIP_edit" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Impuesto</th>
      <th class="hidden">Agencia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tb">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` for this. Using an extra array to keep track of the matches you can filter the double values out. Look at the example below.

```js
//array with data
var data = [
{"id" : 1, "value" : "a"},
{"id" : 2, "value" : "b"},
{"id" : 3, "value" : "b"},
{"id" : 4, "value" : "c"},
{"id" : 5, "value" : "d"},
{"id" : 6, "value" : "a"}
];

var map = [];
result = data.filter(function(element){
    if (map.indexOf(element.value) === -1)
    {
      map.push(element.value);
      return element;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```